# What is the best (fast but contributive) way to get Strunk & White badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta, edit-badges

As far as know, [less than 200 people have a Strunk & White badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) here on Meta.

1. Why there's so few people eligible for this?
2. Feature-request, is editing 80 posts too hard? Can we reduce this to 50?
3. What is the best (fast but contributive) way to get the Strunk & White badge?

Comment: Few people have it here on Meta because most people use this site as a tool for posting feedback rather than participating in content curation. The real question is not whether it's hard for people to try and earn it - it's whether they're actually willing to do so.

Comment: 1. Because not enough people have edited enough posts. Literally all there is to it. 2. Not hard. Just not common, I guess. Why should it be 50? 3. Make edits.

Comment: On Super User, which has a bit less traffic than this site, around 350 people (twice as many) have the badge.

Comment: "*fast but contributive*" without full editing privilege on 2k, it will always be slow because users are limited to a maximum of 5 suggested edits at a time. Otherwise, 100+ rep users can probably just spam-edit any posts on Formatting Sandbox... On the other hand, [there are only 1300+ users with 2k+ reps](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/alltime/meta) here, so more than 10% is big enough, I guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Educated guess: here on Meta we have a small number of regulars who actively curate most content on the site. Perhaps that leaves less room for others to do so, and hence not many users have the badge. I haven't checked how Meta compares to other sites of the same size; that might not even be helpful since Meta is so different from the other sites.
2. The criteria for editing badges (bronze: 1 edit, silver: 80 edits, gold: 500 edits) are a nice mirror of those for flagging badges; both groups are part of the [Moderation badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Some badges being harder to earn than others is not a good reason to break this symmetry; [Archaeologist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/157/archaeologist) is by definition harder to earn than Strunk & White.
3. Make good, significant edits, preferably to active posts. Since you don't have [edit privileges yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) your edits will enter the Suggested Edits review queue, so make them count. As a bonus, you get +2 reputation from each approved edit. You have been member for 4.5 years, but no activity yet; there is enough traffic here every day to help improve the content of a couple of posts.

Comment: @Sonic now I'm wondering whether my definition of "quite a few" (half a dozen, perhaps a few more) corresponds with yours of "a small number of" :)

Comment: Perhaps my prior legacy of [editing without possibility of anyone earning those badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304283/377214) may have denied a few people of earning them.